# SQL - Creating a historical fact table from latest snapshot data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, business-intelligence

I'm currently working on an interesting problem and though I'd share it to solicit ideas.

I have a table, lets call it *Table One*.  Each *ID* has an **effective date range** implied by **datetimes** (these are actually DATETIME types, even though I've presented them strangely below) *Date A* and *Date B*.  So for example, ID 1 was in effect from 1-Nov until 3-Nov.

[image]

From this table, I'd like to produce a table similar to *Target Table* (pictured below), where each ID/Effective Date combination is listed row-by-row:

[image]

To accomplish this, I also have a table containing sequential dates, with the string format for the date, along with a start datetime and an end datetime:

[image]

My experience is mostly with C# and while I could whip up a script to accomplish this, I worry that I would be hacking around what can be accomplished with pure SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with a join, but considering your data types, it's a bit convoluted. The best to do is to use, in your Table One, columns with the DATE datatype, instead of strings. Then you can do something like that :

```
SELECT t2.DateStr, t1.Id
FROM TableOne t1
JOIN TableTwo t2 ON t2 StartDatetime BETWEEN t1.DateA AND t1.DateB
ORDER BY t2.DateStr, t1.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks! They are actually datetimes in "Table One", apologies I presented them differently than those in "Table Two" -- but they are the same data type.

Answer (score 1):

What you need as a calendar table - like you have but using actual `DATETIME`, then just join you data on to it as

```
SELECT c.ShortDate, t.Id, t.StartDate, t.EndDate
FROM dbo.Calendar c
JOIN tbl t ON c.ShortDate BETWEEN t.StartDate AND t.EndDate
ORDER BY c.ShortDate, t.Id
```

Sidenote: keep all dates as `DATETIME` (or related data type) and let the client format it.

Comment: in french : les grands esprits se rencontrent :)

Comment: @t-i Thanks also! They are actually datetimes in "Table One", apologies I presented them differently than those in "Table Two" -- but they are the same data type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that's similar to the others. I do have a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b928a/5) I spent too long creating, though, for what it's worth.

```
SELECT ds.datestr, t1.id 
FROM DateStrings ds
INNER JOIN TableOne t1 
    ON ds.startdate BETWEEN t1.startdate AND t1.EndDate
ORDER BY datestr
```